# postgresql does no restart after changing postgres.conf or pg_hba.conf. This incident happened while i was trying to setup the postgresql BDR

Tags: data-recovery, database, postgresql, database-administration, data-backup

I am not able to login to postgresql after restarting postgresql DB after configuring pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf file. The snapshot of the error is attached for referral [postgresql.conf / pg_hba.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8UUI.png). This incident happened while i was trying to setup the postgresql Bi Directional replication. After this I need to restart the database to take the configuration changes into effect. But when I restart the database the configuration files go missing.

Answer (score 0):

i had the issue that a syntax error in the config file was the problem; i did not get an error or warning (maybe yes but i didn't find it),

so double check your config file and do only one change at one time,

Is "sudo systemctl start postgresql" getting more information?

Or sudo service postgresql status

best,

Bodo

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I followed all the steps mentioned by you. Doesn't work out.